# DocuSign JSON Web Token (JWT) Grant flow returns invalid_grant error, issuer_not_found

Tags: node.js, docusignapi, rest

Docusign returns

> '{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"issuer_not_found"}'

in production account works perfectly fine in demo account.

I feel this is due to invalid env variables supplied but not sure which one is it ? and what is `issuer_not_found` here ?

Followed steps from here => https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/post-go-live?_ga=2.10305266.631111297.1594877013-2137473900.1593156394

Answer (score 1):

The issue was `authServer` pointing to demo authentication server. It should be `authServer: "account.docusign.com"` instead.

Comment: https://support.docusign.com/articles/DocuSign-Developer-Support-FAQs#Troubleshoot-JWT-invalid_grant mentions:
 **Issuer_not_found**: The integration key in the iss (issuer) parameter is unavailable in the current environment. This can also mean a mismatch in the aud (audience) value and the environment being hit: for example, using an aud value of account.docusign.com while requesting a token from https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token.